# .addEventListener("load") only firing twice in a "loop"

Tags: javascript

What am doing is not a loop, what is it called?

I am trying to Sequentially load images after the DOM is loaded, to be animated later. For some reason this is only loads two images, there are 20.

Hope someone knows why, thanks.

```js
function init() {
  var imgDefer = document.querySelectorAll(".img-sequence");
  var lastLoadIndex = 0;

  function loadNextImage() {
    if (imgDefer.length === lastLoadIndex) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("loading image at index " + lastLoadIndex);
    imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].setAttribute(
      "src",
      imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].getAttribute("data-src")
    );
    lastLoadIndex += 1;
    // console.log(lastLoadIndex);
  };
  imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].addEventListener("load", loadNextImage);
  loadNextImage();
  //console.log(imgDefer.length);
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=0" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=1" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=2" /><img class="img-sequence"
    data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=3" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=4" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=5" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=6"
  /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=7" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=8" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=9" /><img class="img-sequence"
    data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=10" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=11" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=12" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=13"
  /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=14" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=15" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=16" /><img class="img-sequence"
    data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=17" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=18" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=19" />
</div>
```

Comment: For the future, whenever possible please use SO's Snippets, not external code reference sites like codepen or jsfiddle or others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are doing the `.addEventListener()` **after your loop is done (not inside of it)**, only one image is getting a callback registered (the last one). And, right after that, you are manually calling the callback, so it runs a second time.

You should move the `.addEventListener()` code to be inside of the loop so that each image gets a callback. Make sure you place it before you increment your counter so you don't wind up skipping the first image.

As far as what you call what you are doing.... Well, it is a loop. It's looping through a node-list and configuring an event handler for each.

```js
function init() {
  var imgDefer = document.querySelectorAll(".img-sequence");
  var lastLoadIndex = 0;

  function loadNextImage() {
    if (imgDefer.length === lastLoadIndex) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("loading image at index " + lastLoadIndex);
    imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].setAttribute(
      "src",
      imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].getAttribute("data-src")
    );
    imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].addEventListener("load", loadNextImage);
    
    lastLoadIndex += 1;
    // console.log(lastLoadIndex);
    
  };

  loadNextImage();
  //console.log(imgDefer.length);
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=0" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=1" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=2" /><img class="img-sequence"
    data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=3" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=4" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=5" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=6"
  /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=7" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=8" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=9" /><img class="img-sequence"
    data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=10" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=11" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=12" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=13"
  /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=14" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=15" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=16" /><img class="img-sequence"
    data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=17" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=18" /><img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=19" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The event subscription should be inside the `loadNextImage` function.

```
function init() {
  var imgDefer = document.querySelectorAll(".img-sequence");
  var lastLoadIndex = 0;
  function loadNextImage() {
    if (imgDefer.length === lastLoadIndex) {
      return;
    }

    // Here
    imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].addEventListener("load", loadNextImage);
    imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].setAttribute(
      "src",
      imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].getAttribute("data-src")
    );
    lastLoadIndex += 1;
  };
  loadNextImage();
}
```